# How do I properly use fread() and fwrite() in my program?

Tags: c, file, io, fwrite, fread

```
/*Write a program that indefinitely takes in files to append to a master
  file. If the file names are the same, don't do it. If there's an error,
  don't do it. Exit with a blank line. Use a custom buffer.*/ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NAME 25
#define BUFSIZE 1024
int append(FILE *, FILE *); 

int main(){
    char src[MAX_NAME], mainfile[MAX_NAME]; 
    FILE *src_ptr, *mainfile_ptr; 
    int successes = 0; 

    puts("Enter name of main file"); 
    if(gets(mainfile) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, couldn't get filename\n"); 
        return 1; 
    }
    if((mainfile_ptr = fopen(mainfile, "ab")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, couldn't open mainfile\n");
        return 1; 
    }

    do{
        puts("Enter a filename to be appended"); 
        if(gets(src) == NULL || src[0] == '\0' || strcmp(src, mainfile) == 0){
            if(src[0])
                puts("Error, couldn't get filename!"); 
            continue; 
        } 

        if((src_ptr =fopen(src, "rb")) == NULL){
            puts("Error, could not open file");
            continue; 
        }

        if(setvbuf(src_ptr, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFSIZE) != 0){
            puts("Couldn't create filebuffer!"); 
            continue; 
        }

        if(append(src_ptr, mainfile_ptr) != 0){
            fflush(src_ptr); 
            puts("Couldn't append!"); 
            continue; 
        }

        fclose(src_ptr); 
        ++successes; 
        printf("Successfully appended %s, %d files total\n", src, successes);

    }while(src[0] != '\0'); 

    fclose(mainfile_ptr); 
    printf("Successfully appended %d files, bye!\n", successes); 
    return 0; 
}


int append(FILE *src, FILE *mainfile){
    size_t bytes = 0; 
    static char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    while(bytes = (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)
       fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, mainfile);  

    if(ferror(src) || ferror(mainfile))
        return 1; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Hi there. Per a C Primer Plus example, I wrote a program that would append the contents of 
user-specified files to a master file. Initially I wrote it intending only to use it with
text files, but then I changed it to work in binary mode. I used it to append four files. I got some really weird results and I don't know why. Here's a screenshot of the finished
file (I had to screenshot it because it's full of really weird characters). I get the same
results without opening them in binary mode with fopen. It seems to "append" my files
multiple times, some of which only half way and then later the other half.

Where did I go wrong?

[image: File being viewed in gvim]

I don't know why it resized it so much.

Comment: `gets` will be abolished.

Comment: Possibly too meta, but `strcmp` is not a good way to test if your input file is the same as your output file. Excercise: Can you name one or more reasons why?

Comment: Please note that you should never use the `gets()` function, which is fundamentally inherently unsafe. This function was deprecated in C99, and left out of C11 entirely.

Answer (score 9):

```
while(bytes = (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, mainfile);
```

should be

```
while((bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), bytes, mainfile);
```

In the cases where `fread` returns less than `BUFSIZE` bytes, you're writing data from previous reads into `mainfile`.

You could also check that `fwrite` returns `bytes`, choosing whether to abort or retry writing the remainder of the buffer if less is written.

Comment: I think you means: `while( (bytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)` , left `(` before `bytes =` **?**

Comment: Oh gosh, you're right. When the buffer isn't completely full, I'm still writing BUFSIZE bytes instead of the actual amount that was read.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks, I'd missed that.  Now added to my answer.